# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. at HTMLButtonElement.comm

Tags: javascript

I am beginner in JavaScript and I'd like to take two inputs and print the written text in input text on bottom screen just like to-do app JavaScript, but I'm getting the mentioned error. (See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccDWu.png))

**JS code**

```
var array=[];

function naam() 
{

var list = document.createElement("ul");        
var inputname=document.getElementById("nameplace").value;     
   list.innerText=inputname;    
    array.push(list);    
    if (inputname ==""|| inputname == " "){    
        alert("kuch tu likho");
    }    
    else {    
        var naam1= document.getElementById("naamprint");    
        naam1.appendChild(list);    
    }
}


var array1=[];

function comm() {    
    var list1=document.createElement("ul");    
    var inputname1=document.getElementById("commentplace").value;    
    list1.innerText=inputname1;    
    array1.push(list1);    
    if (inputname1 =="" || inputname1 ==" "){
        alert("kuch to likho");
    }
    else {

        var naam2=document.getElementById("commentprint");    
        naam2.appendChild(comm);
    }
}

var action=document.getElementById("btn");    
action.onclick=naam;    
action.onclick=comm;
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Name <input type="text" id="nameplace"></p>
<p>Comment <input type="text" id="commentplace" ></p>
<button id="btn"> submit </button>
<p><b id="naamprint"></p></b>
<p><b id="commentprint"></p></b>
<script src="app.js"> </script>
```

Comment: `comm` in `comm` function refers to the function itself, it is not an element. You need to append `list1` instead of `comm`. Also, `ul` element can't have text node as a direct content, hence setting `list1.innerText=inputname1;` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Hmm... at least FF places a text node directly to `ul` element, but that is invalid HTML ... See [`<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul).

Comment: now what i write on comment and press submit its print but name doesnot i want to print name and comment on screen at the same time thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should add a static empty `ul` element to your HTML, and create `li` element, add some text to it, and append that `li` to the existing `ul` element?

Comment: @lealceldeiro Looks like you've edited the HTML part out from the question?

Comment: <p>Name     <input type="text" id="nameplace"></p> 
    
<p>Comment  <input type="text" id="commentplace" ></p>
    
<button id="btn"> submit </button>    
    <p ><b id="naamprint"> </p> </b>
    <p ><b id="commentprint"> </p> </b>
    <script src="app.js"> </script>

Comment: One more thing, you can add only a single click handler using `onclick` property, you need `addEventListener` to add multiple click events. Althought, you could combine the functions to a single function ...

Comment: @Teemu yes just like this have a look https://sky-school.firebaseapp.com/project/TodoApp/index.html

it has one input field i have two input field

Comment: Oh!, You are right, @Teemu. I'm really sorry about this, it was a mistake of mine. I hope it did not interfere in finding a solution. Again, apologies for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer

```
naam2.appendChild(comm); // error because comm is not an element that you can append
```

Change to

```
naam2.appendChild(list1);
```

Plus, you define one listener and that redefine it

```
action.onclick=naam;    // this will never execute
action.onclick=comm;
```

Change to

```
action.addEventListener('click', naam);
action.addEventListener('click', comm);
```

Few more comments:

a. close inner tag first

```
<p><b id="naamprint"></p></b> // change to </b></p>
<p><b id="commentprint"></p></b> // same situation
```

b. You can simply use `nameplace.value` instead of `document.getElementById("nameplace").value` it works for any element with ID. for example this

```
var naam2=document.getElementById("commentprint");    
naam2.appendChild(comm);
```

can be simplified to this

```
commentprint.appendChild(comm);
```

c. ul tag.

`var list1=document.createElement("ul");` `ul` tag should contain `li` tag, not text.

d. spaces in value. this:

```
if (inputname1 =="" || inputname1 ==" "){ ...
```

should better be changed by this

```
if (!inputname1.trim()){ ...
```

Comment: Thanks Alot @qiAlex

Comment: Welcome, Saad. Yes, ul is not for text, Teemu. To be honest, almost every line in this example is not perfect, I just suggest minimum to make code works

Comment: Well, now the answer addresses all the gotchas, and even some extra = ).

Comment: Thank you, Teemu :)